# Postgres trigger not updating specified column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the below user table

```
  Column   |           Type           |                       Modifiers                       
-----------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer                  | not null default nextval('accounts_id_seq'::regclass)
 username  | character varying(40)    | 
 email     | character varying(40)    | 
 password  | character varying        | 
 join_date | timestamp with time zone | default now()
 xp        | integer                  | default 0
 level     | integer                  | default 1
 provider  | character varying        | 
 is_admin  | boolean                  | default false
```

I'm trying to create a trigger which looks at the user xp INTEGER and updates his level based on the given xp

this is my below function and necessary trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_user_level() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $level$

  BEGIN

    CASE 
      WHEN NEW.xp BETWEEN 100 AND 200 THEN
        NEW.level = 2;
      WHEN NEW.xp BETWEEN 200 AND 400 THEN
        NEW.level = 3;
      ELSE
        NEW.level = 1;
    END CASE;

    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$level$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER set_user_level AFTER UPDATE ON account FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_user_level();
```

However , whenever i update the user xp . The user level still stays at 1. Is there something wrong with my syntax? I pretty much used the same syntax as specified in the docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a `BEFORE` instead of an `AFTER` update in your case, and your code will work perfectly.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ef408/1

You may read a bit about triggers [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/trigger-definition.html).

Interesting sample :

> Typically, row-level BEFORE triggers are used for checking or
>   modifying the data that will be inserted or updated. For example, a
>   BEFORE trigger might be used to insert the current time into a
>   timestamp column, or to check that two elements of the row are
>   consistent. Row-level AFTER triggers are most sensibly used to
>   propagate the updates to other tables, or make consistency checks
>   against other tables. The reason for this division of labor is that an
>   AFTER trigger can be certain it is seeing the final value of the row,
>   while a BEFORE trigger cannot; there might be other BEFORE triggers
>   firing after it. If you have no specific reason to make a trigger
>   BEFORE or AFTER, the BEFORE case is more efficient, since the
>   information about the operation doesn't have to be saved until end of
>   statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. i was thinking of a whole new meaning of BEFORE and AFTER. ill try this right away .. also , would you by any chance be able to clarify what exactly the $level$ syntax means when creating the function? that is something which i'm unable to figure out but is specified in the docs

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING .

Comment: I was stumped for a bit, and then i realized i had my trigger firing off on STATEMENT and not for each ROW. And so modifying the new in the postgres function wasnt doing anything